# Can we create 1-1 chatDialog without setting "occupantIDs”? (Quickblox)

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

I am always getting error code 400. below is the block from [quickblox sample code](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios2#Create_new_1-1.28private.29_chat_dialog)!. But ChatDialog will create when we set "occupantIDs". Is it mandatory to set "occupantIDs" field if the chat type is 1-1 (Private)?

```
var chatDialog = QBChatDialog()
chatDialog.type = QBChatDialogType.Private

QBRequest.createDialog(chatDialog, successBlock: { (response: QBResponse!, createdDialog: QBChatDialog!) -> Void in
            println("*** Created new chat dialog *****")
        }, errorBlock: { (response: QBResponse!) -> Void in
            println("*** errorBlock *****")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with 1-1 chat you have to provide an ID of other user. Don't need to provide your own ID here.